# Suspected IIS7.5 Connector Issue Tomcat & Coldfusion 10 if over certain size ajax call

Tags: ajax, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have test a form submission on my local testing server and all is good.

However once the code is uploaded to Coldfusion 10 on IIS7.5 it fails.

Basically if I have 2 contact details on the screen its fine, if there are three it refuses to update via ajax (called via ajaximport).

The url length is 2.48kb, the error varies from

```
"NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure"
```

Other times I get a 500 server error with

http://m.yapcrm.com/sites/dump/ii7errorlongajaxcall.cfm

I have checked the usual subjects and tweaked the server, but no joy..

Best I can figure its the connector to Tomcat as its the ISAPifilter picking up the issue.

In short, any hints or help would be great!!

Comment: Have you tested this in different browsers? Could be a browser-specific url length limit? iirc, general advice is not to have urls longer than 2048 characters, but different browsers/versions have impose different (or none) limits on this.

Comment: What is your patch level? Are you aware of all the problems people have been having with CF10 & IIS?  It might be worth reading through the comments against this blog article: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-4-is-now-available

Comment: It works fine on the testing server on the same browser + different machines. PC/Macs. Safari/Firefox & Chrome. Interesting about 2048. I suppose i could split each contact into a different call, all via the same save button.

Comment: Both servers are running the Patch 4.. only difference is one is running internal server + one is on a fresh install of IIS7.5

Comment: If you're updating data (which it looks like you are) then I'd switch over to POST as the method, which will remove any problems with the length of the content you're sending.

Comment: As I understand it, the "browser limits" are related to URLs in the address bar, not "URLs in general".  I agree with @barnyr that whilst there's obviously some unexpected issue here, you should really be using a POST, in which case you won't be affected by whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, no solution was found. However changing the default method from Get to Post

Example for reference anybody else.

```
    var submitForm = new UpdateContact();
            **submitForm.setHTTPMethod("POST");**               
            submitForm.setCallbackHandler(response);
            submitForm.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
            submitForm.setForm("testValidator");                
            submitForm.UpdateContact();
```

UpdateContact() being the CFC method called via cfAjaxProxy.